# Third party js not loading in Magento 2.3.4

Tags: magento2, javascript, requirejs-config.js

I am trying to load 2 third party js files in my module,

Followed below steps.

**Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/default.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">

<body>
    <referenceContainer name="after.body.start">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" 
            name="mobile-megamenu.file" 
            before="-" 
            template="Vendor_Module::custom.phtml"
        />
    </referenceContainer>  
</body>
```

**Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/custom.phtml**

```
<div id="dl-menu" class="dl-menuwrapper">
                    <button class="dl-trigger">More</button>
                    <ul class="dl-menu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" class="levelTwo">Test</a>
                            <ul class="dl-submenu">
                             <li>Test </li>
                              <li>Test </li>
                               <li>Test </li>
                                <li>Test </li>
                    </ul>
                 </div>

<script>    
    require([
        "jquery",
        "dlmenu",
        "modernizr"
    ], function ($) {

       $(document).ready(function(){

           $( '#dl-menu' ).dlmenu({
                    animationClasses : { classin : 'dl-animate-in-2', classout : 'dl-animate-out-2' }
            });           
            $("button.dl-trigger").click(function(){
                $("ul.extra-links").toggle();
            });
        });
    }); 

 </script>
```

**Vendor/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
   map: {
      '*': {
      dlmenu: 'Vendor_Module/js/jquery.dlmenu',
      modernizr:'Vendor_Module/js/modernizr.custom'
     }
   }
};
```

I have Moved both the js files here,

app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/

I am getting the following errors in console.

> require.js:166 Uncaught Error: Script error for: dlmenu.
>
> Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot read property 'prefixed' of undefined

Can someone help me on this please. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have an issue with your requirejs-config.js file, it should be :

```
var config = {
    paths: {
        dlmenu: 'Vendor_Module/js/jquery.dlmenu',
        modernizr:'Vendor_Module/js/modernizr.custom'
    },
    shim: {
        "dlmenu": ["jquery"],
    }
};
```

You can use deps instead of paths depending on your need.
Shim is used to load jquery before dlmenu.

Comment: Hi @Taschert, thanks for the answer, okay I will check it, have u tried it? I have treis it before but didn't work for me

Comment: Thanks @Taschert, its worked